# Подключение домена reg.ru на freehosting.com

Tags: хостинг, dns, домен

У меня есть уже купленный домен на reg.ru (information-app.xyz). Пытаюсь связать его с хостингом freehosting.com

[image: На reg.ru уже прописал DNS сервисы, там пишет, что нужно обратится к хостинг провайдеру]
На reg.ru уже прописал DNS сервисы, там пишет, что нужно обратится к хостинг провайдеру

[image: На freehosting.com есть вкладка DNS management]

На freehosting.com есть вкладка DNS management

[image: ошибка]

Когда пытаюсь туда нажать, то выскакивает такая табличка, что у вас недостаточно прав, по-моему нужно войти с правами админа, но как это сделать?

Панель: DirectAdmin

Comment: Вам не кажется что для таких вопросов есть техническая поддержка что в reg.ru что в freehosting.com ? Они отвечают в течении нескольких минут а вы тут уже 40 минут ждете ответ

Comment: В том-то и дело, не отвечают

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает что ручная правка DNS это платная доп услуга. Не раз встречал такие хостинги

Comment: И что мне делать? Ждать поддержки?

Comment: Ну вам должны были предоставить белый ip на freehosting.com. отредактируйте DNS на reg.ru таким образом чтоб он ссылался на этот ip  все будет работать. Хотя нюансы  могут быть. Такие вопросы конечно-же лучше решать с самим провайдером тк я не вижу нужную информациею в отличии от них.

Comment: Нужно ли добавлять DNS сервера на reg.ru (ns1.freehosting.com и ns2.freehosting.com) или оставлять эти (ns1.reg.ru, ns2.reg.ru)?

Comment: https://www.reg.ru/support/dns/DNS-servery/kak-privyazat-domen-k-svoemu-domashnemu-ip

Comment: согласно инструкции... оставляем только ns1.reg.ru, ns2.reg.ru. Так же стоит учесть то что привязка может сработать через 5 минут а может через сутки

Comment: Спасибо, буду ждать